# React with Ant Design - How to share state between multiple <Select> on a <Form>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd, ant-design-pro

I am new to ReactJS and AntDesign.

I am trying to get a set of `<Select>` components to share state, so when you select the first one, it populates the options of the next ones on the form, it has to be a `<Select>`, I cannot use a `<Cascade>` as it is going to complicate UI too much ( users are not very versed with computers ).

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, the data on useEffect will come from the backend in a single request

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xarwcj-sghpze?file=index.js

After you select the first option, I expected the second dropdown to be filled up with the child array, but instead I get an empty dropdown.

I am pretty sure the value is being set but React or Ant is not rerendering it because of some misconfiguration on my part, but I cannot understand why.

Comment: I see two problems right of the bat. First, `value` in this call `formInstance.setFieldsValue({ subList: value.list });` is just the id of the selected item so `value.list` returns undefined. You'll need to find the related object `const sub = list.find(o => o.id === value);`. Secondly, the `setFieldsValue` isn't calling a rerender.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!, how can I make setFieldsValue call a rerender?

Comment: I think it was calling one all along actually, but since you had passed `undefined` to `setFieldsValue` it wasn't rendering the second select. Not sure why you're getting the `map` error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use antd `Form` then you must wrap your input elements in `Form.Item` components. And `Form.Item` components have a `name` prop. When you use any `formInstance` methods that `name` that you give to your `Form.Item` is how you can reference the given input component. So when you were doing `formInstance.setFieldsValue({ subList: value.list });` you didn't actually have a `subList` form item, so I think that's why antd didn't set it's value.

With that said, your second select should look something like this:

```
<Form.Item name="subList">
  <Select ... >
    {formInstance.getFieldValue("subList")?.map ... }
  </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

Don't forget to wrap that first `Select` too, and any other input components in your `Form` for that matter. The names you give to the `Form.Item` is how you will be able to read the values in the `Form`'s `onFinish` method.

For a working example of such usage you can check this example from the antd form docs: https://codesandbox.io/s/n1zdn.

I should mention that to me it seems erronous when you do `formInstance.setFieldsValue({ subList: value.list });` in your first `Select`'s `onChange` (because `value` is a number, so `value.list` is undefined), but I believe that's because what you provided is only a rough, incomplete copy of your actual code. However, If you have further difficulties with this issue please drop a comment and I'll do my best to help out more!

## Edit

To answer your comment, the problem I managed to identify was that, when selecting an option from the first select, you were setting the **value** of the second select as an **array**. What you actually wanted to do was set the available options of the second select, not it's value.

So the changes I propose is for you to set the options of the second select in a state variable, like so:

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
const [secondList, setSecondList] = useState([]);

// ...

return (
    <>
      <Form form={formInstance}>
        <Form.Item>
          <Select
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            onSelect={value => {
              console.log(list.find(o => o.id === value).list);
              setSecondList(list.find(o => o.id === value).list);
            }}
          >
            {list.map(value => {
              return (
                <Option key={value.id} value={value.id}>
                  {value.name}
                </Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>

        <br />
        <br />

        <Form.Item name="subList">
          <Select
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            onChange={value => {
              console.log(value);
            }}
          >
            {secondList?.map(value => {
              return (
                <Option key={value.id} value={value.id}>
                  {value.desc}
                </Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment! I I forgot to add the <Form.Item> in this sample too. Here is an updated version with all your points. I still can't make it work. Would you mind having another look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xarwcj-sghpze?file=index.js

Comment: I see, that indeed solves it. It's weird I use the form State to just set an random field to the array and iterate over it to generate the options.